# force 2 decimal places in PHP without commas when variable given could have no value

Tags: php, numbers, int

I need to take a $_POST variable and force it to have 2 decimal places with no commas.

The below works but surely this cant be the best way to do this.

```
$difference = str_replace(",","",number_format((int)$_POST["difference"],2));
```

I put the `(int)$_POST["difference"],2)` so it would convert a null value to 0 and prevent the warning `number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given ...`as some of the form inputs on the previous page may not have been used.

As I said, this does work. Mainly I'm worried about unintended side effects from doing it this way as it doesn't seem very clean.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 number_format((float)$number, 2, '.', '');
```

another way:

```
sprintf('%0.2f', $unpadded); // 520 -> 520.00
```

Comment: Wow, I totally missed that you could specify the thousands separator in the documentation for `number_format()`  Thank you very much!